# Encoding a SELECT statement as JSON, iOS issues

Tags: php, mysql, ios, arrays, json

I am trying to JSON encode the results of my SQL SELECT statement using PHP and am unsure if I am formatting my array correctly before encoding.

My PHP code is:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT  CLINIC.clinic_name AS "clinicname" FROM CLINIC ORDER BY CLINIC.clinic_name ASC');

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($clinicname);            
$test = array();                   
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $tempArray = array('clinicname' => $clinicname);
    array_push($test, $tempArray);
}
$stmt->close();

// Return clinics, encoded with JSON
header('Content-type: application/json');

$json = json_encode($test);
echo $json;
```

The result of this array creation and encoding is:

```
[{"clinicname":"Bangor"},{"clinicname":"Belfast"},{"clinicname":"Crumlin"},{"clinicname":"Londonderry"}]
```

So I have an array of arrays.

Will this be okay for sending as JSON? All the examples I see seem to be a single array. Am I correct so far?

And then, regarding iOS, will the received object be a NSDictionary or an NSArray?

Any help or feedback on the above would be greatly received.

- Matt.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your JSON is properly formatted.  Next time you can use a [JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com/) to check.

Also, some details on [json_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

A [] represents an array and {} represents an object.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, if this is the result from an http request, it will be of type NSString, and then need to be parsed by something like:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

which then converts it to NSArray, NSDictionary NSString, etc.

Comment: Many thanks for the responses. Ok, I am using the JSONKit to convert the responseString into an NSArray or NSDictionary. Ultimately, I need to be able to grab all the values for a specific key (in this case 'clinicname'). How would be the best way to do this in Objective-C? How can i return a value for a key when the key is the same everytime? Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can send an array of arrays, and you can acces like the follow way:

```
$response = json_decode($response,true);

  foreach ($response as $resp)
  {
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($resp);
  }
```

json example:

```
[{"id":"38","first_name":"prueba","second_name":"example","first_surname":"prueba","second_surname":"GONZALEZ","email":"x@x.net","network_login":"x.x","pos_name":"x x","position":"1","active":"1"},{"vhur":"292","first_name":"c","second_name":"example","first_surname":"example","second_surname":null,"email":"example@example.com","network_login":"example.example","pos_name":"example example","position":"2","active":"1"}]
```